# PHP a function in a functions argument?

Tags: php

Is it possible to call a function as a function argument?
I'm trying to get the value of the bar function and pass it to the foo function.

If I try to set the function to a variable

e.g.

```
$foobar = bar($x)
```

it will execute the function where ever the variable is found.

e.g.

```
function bar($x) {
    $x = 1;
    return 1;
}
function foo(x) {
    $x += $x;
    echo $x;
}

foo(bar($x));
```

Comment: Have you tried converting the pseudo-code to actual PHP code and running it?

Comment: This looks like phpreboot syntax, not php.

Comment: $ before the name of the variable?

Comment: What makes you think it shouldn't work? And how is that in any way related to functional programming?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do this in PHP, and virtually all high level programming languages. `bar($x)` will be evaluated, and its return value will be passed as the argument to `foo()`.

Comment: Thank you. I made it 10 years ago. PHP is pretty old. ;)

Comment: I made a similar avatar a while back, but the delimiters were in red, I used `<?php` and I didn't have a function call in the middle. Fun stuff!

Comment: Dan what languages would you recommend?

Comment: Recommend for what? I recommend programming in whatever language you know best.

Answer (score 0):

`x` should be `$x`, other than that there's nothing wrong with your code. The answer is 'yes, you can use a function call as an argument in another function. It's pretty standard stuff.